Wittgenstein's Tractatus, 2.15121
Some context from Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus:

2.151 The form of representation is the possibility that the things are combined with one another as are the elements of the picture.


2.1511 Thus the picture is linked with reality; it reaches up to it.


2.1512 It is like a scale applied to reality.


2.15121 Only the outermost points of the dividing lines touch the object to be measured.


2.1513 According to this view the representing relation which makes it a picture, also belongs to the picture.

I am having difficulty understanding Wittgenstein: I understand 2.1513, but what is 2.15121 referring to here? What are these "dividing lines"?
He later asserts that a picture represents its object from without, so why does 2.15121 seem to imply that the object is being measured/represented "from within"?

@andrós Thank you, my fault. I am reading from a pdf, and it seems that this line is missing.

A different translation makes it more coherent:"That is how a picture is attached to reality; it reaches right out to it. 2.1512 It is laid against reality like a measure. 2.15121 Only the end-points of the graduating lines actually touch the object that is to be measured."

See Morris p.139:"The claim of 2.15121 then becomes something like this: nothing matters about the elements of a picture or model other than that they have the same ranges of possibilities of combination as the items in reality with which they are correlated. No further similarity is required. And this amounts, in effect, to the claim that the elements of a picture or model are arbitrary signs: whatever representational work the elements of a picture may do, it can be done by quite different things 1/2

provided that those different things have the same possibilities of combination with other things. The point of the
remark, on this interpretation, is to insist that representation only requires a very abstract kind of similarity between
representation and reality: nothing more than sameness of
form." 2/2

Perhaps this is related to recent questions about Identity, Uniqueness and Affection?
